# Are these two statements about vector addition equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Statement 1** Vector addition: This operation takes two vectors $u,v$ in vector space $V$ and returns the vector $u+v$ in vector space $V$.

**Statement 2** Every vector $v$ in the vector space $V$ can be expressed as the sum of two vectors.

Are Statement 1 and Statement 2 same in meaning?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user Could you please explain the reason or give some examples. I am not able to see exactly.

Comment: One is about writing the sum of two random vectors and getting a third vector, the second is about taking a vector and writing it as a sum. They are not at all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, these are not the same.

Addition on a vector space $V$ is a map $V\times V \to V$, $(u, v) \mapsto u + v$.

Statement $1$ says this map exists, while statement $2$ says this map is surjective.